# Measure every single command within a bash file?

Tags: command-line, bash, time

Is there a way to measure the time spent in every single command within a bash file? Hence, put time in front of every command. The quantity of commands is unknown right now, as I intend to use this time measure for future bash scripts, too. And also worth mentioning is that I intend to only run simple bash scripts having command1, command2, command3, ... etc. Hence, no complex higher logic scripts.

Lets say I have a bash file similar to this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

mv /path/to/file /other/path/
cd /other/path/
tar -xzf /other/path/file
```

Is there a way to get some output similar to this?

```
 6.553s   mv /path/to/file /other/path/
 0.057s   cd /other/path/
19.088s   tar -xzf /other/path/file
```

I know that with `time` I can get the time spent of a single command. But I am looking for a solution for measuring the time of every command itself.

Comment: So you put time in front of every command.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes. I want the time duration of every command.

Comment: What Socrates suggested is to place "time" before every line in your script in order to have the time duration for every command. You could use "sed" to automatically prepend "time" to each line, but it might not be worth the effort if you have only a few lines in your script.

Comment: Probably the closest you will get is something like this: [How to debug a bash script and get execution time per command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27559164/4440445)

Comment: How many commands are there in the shellscript? Can you 'put time' there manually, or are you looking for an automatic way to do it?

Comment: @sudodus In the above example I want to measure 3 commands, but generally I want to use it for other future scripts, too. Hence, the number of commands is unknown. I updated the post.

Comment: @Rinzwind I kind of did that by combining the answers of sudous and wjandrea. First getting the lines of a file, then running them through `/usr/bin/time`. If this is the only way, this might be a possible solution.

Comment: The basic solution: to add the text string according to my answer to every line is not the best one, probably it will fail in a more advanced script, because the syntax will be destroyed (depending on what syntax you use). It is better to identify what are external commands, executable programs and shell buittin  commands and other shellscripts and add the text string according to my answer in front of those. Maybe you (or someone else) can create a script, that helps you identify those commands and add the text string only to the relevant lines.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, of course! I didn't even think of higher logic in bash scripts! I only thought of simple commands like command1, command2, command3, ... Mea culpa! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I did some testing, and timing of shell builtin commands don't work this way. In your example **`cd`** is affected. On the other hand it is very fast (and most shell builtin commands are rather fast).

Comment: @sudodus True. So putting an `if` before `time` checking whether it is a shell keyword or not, could be a solution. Do you know any way of getting `true/false` to check whether a command is a shell keyword?

Comment: @Socrates, I added example with a shellscript. I hope it will help doing what you want in a more automatic way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `/usr/bin/time` with the option `-f` like the following example. Preceed each command in your shellscript with `/usr/bin/time -f "%E %C"`

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%E %C" sleep 2.34
0:02.34 sleep 2.34
```

See `man time` for more details.

Example:

I made a small script, that can work to modify a **simple** shellscript by identifying commands, that can be tested with `/usr/bin/time`. Let us use the name `time2script`.

```
#!/bin/bash

string='/usr/bin/time -f "%E %C"'

while IFS= read -r line
do
 cmd=$(<<< "$line" sed -e 's/ *//'|cut -d ' ' -f1)
 command=$(which "$cmd")
 if [ "$command" != "" ]
 then
  printf '%s %s\n' "$string" "$line"
 else
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
 fi
done < "$1"
```

Using `time2script` on the example in the edited question:

```
$ ./time2script socrates1
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/time -f "%E %C" mv /path/to/file /other/path/
cd /other/path/
/usr/bin/time -f "%E %C" tar -xzf /other/path/file
```

Redirect to create a modified shellscript,

```
./time2script socrates1 > socrates1-timing
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the naive approach. It has a few points of failure*, so I don't necessarily recommend using it, just wanted to mention it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Time each command in another Bash script.

script="$1"

# Skip blank lines and comments.
grep -vE "^\s*($|#)" "$script" |
    while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    time eval "$line"
done
```

Example script foo.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
true
sleep 2.34
```

Example run:

```
$ bash naive_timer.sh foo.sh
true

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
sleep 2.34

real    0m2.342s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

---

* E.g. `eval` will choke on multi-line commands, like function declarations, array declarations, heredocs, even multi-line quotes. And commands that rely on the value of `$0` may not work.